# Google Sheet formula: how to simplify a formula with multiple COUNTAs

Tags: google-sheets-formula, formula

I have this formula in Google sheets:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sessions data - BQ'!A2:A,'Sessions data - BQ'!B2:B=A4,VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)>=VALUE(B4-B1),VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)<=VALUE(B4-1))),))

+COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sessions data - BQ'!A2:A,'Sessions data - BQ'!B2:B=A5,VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)>=VALUE(B4-B1),VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)<=VALUE(B4-1))),))

+COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sessions data - BQ'!A2:A,'Sessions data - BQ'!B2:B=A6,VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)>=VALUE(B4-B1),VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)<=VALUE(B4-1))),)) ...
```

Initially, I wanted to count the number of entries for a URL in cell A4, so I was using the following formula:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sessions data - BQ'!A2:A,'Sessions data - BQ'!B2:B=A4,VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)>=VALUE(B4-B1),VALUE('Sessions data - BQ'!C2:C)<=VALUE(B4-1))),))
```

Later on I was asked to track several URLs so I added +COUNTA in A5 and +COUNTA in A6 (the two additional rows that you can see in my initial formula above).

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify this formula instead of adding +COUNT every time I want to track a new URL in column A.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVHMEc7Rmlydvegdpe6AFTXVPlhR4ZsmwMQkUJX7omc/edit#gid=0

Here is my Google sheets sample to better understand my issue.

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow just added a sample sheet

Comment: the shared sheet has *restrcited* access

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that and thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=counta(unique(ifna(filter('Raw data sample'!A:A,xmatch('Raw data sample'!B:B,A4:A),isbetween('Raw data sample'!C:C,B4-B1,B4-1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked beautifully thanks! Had to do a tiny twist on my original sheet since the date format was not matching from one sheet to another, apart of this it works as expected.
Also did not know about XMATCH and ISBETWEEN, pretty useful stuffs.